# C# WCF Client - DataTable to XmlElement

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core

I have

- an old WCF SOAP service from my server,
- an .NET Framework application.
- an .NET Framework library.

I want to upgrade my library first to netstandard2.0.
Everything works well, i can regenerate WCF Client files.
However, `DataTable` have changed to `...TableResult` with `XmlElement`.

So, i know how to change `XmlElement` to `DataTable`, but how do I change `DataTable` to `XmlElement`?

```
public static class Transform
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(XmlElement xmlElement)
    {
        using var reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlElement);
        var datatable = new DataTable();
        datatable.ReadXml(reader);
        return datatable;
    }


    public static XmlElement ToXmlElement(DataTable datatable)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GroupBy` to group the rows, then select the parts you want into `XElements`.

Here is an example:

```
        var xml = new XElement(table.TableName, table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            .GroupBy(row => (string)row[0])
            .Select(g =>
                new XElement(table.Columns[0].ColumnName,
                    new XElement("label", g.Key),
                    g.GroupBy(row => (string)row[1])
                     .Select(g1 =>
                        new XElement(table.Columns[1].ColumnName,
                            new XElement("label", g1.Key),
                            new XElement(table.Columns[2].ColumnName,
                                g1.Select(row =>
                                    new XElement("label", (string)row[2])
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

or you can use dataset

```
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       ds.Tables.Add(table);
       XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
       Console.WriteLine(ds.GetXml().ToString());
       // In your case:
       return XMLDoc.DocumentElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ds.Write.xml`, this will have a Stream to put the output into. If you need it, try the method below:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToXml(this DataSet ds)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, ds);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

USAGE:

```
var xmlString = ds.ToXml();

Response.Write(ds.ToXml());
```

And you can check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/writing-dataset-contents-as-xml-data?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for help.